# Is it healthier to live by the coast or inland?

Tags: water

I've asked this question on life hacks and been told to go ask it on medical or travel. It's nothing to do with travel in my opinion. I have heard/ read so many conflicting statistics about the sea air and cloud cover. I would like to know if it is healthier overall to live on the coast or inland.

Answer (score 2):

Being near water appears to make people happy, British newspaper the Guardian ran this piece on it:
https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2019/nov/03/blue-space-living-near-water-good-secret-of-happiness

It contains links to peer reviewed papers about the positive effects of being or living near water or on the coast on well-being, like [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1353829213000816).
The newspaper article and the scientific papers deal with psychological well-being, you would have to look elsewhere for purely physical effects.